# How to restore my iterm2/zsh session after restart?

Tags: macos, zsh, reboot, session, iterm2

I use `oh-my-zsh` with `iTerm2` on `osx` and I'd like them to retain the same tabs with the same directories and hopefully the same textual history after a restart.

Currently after a restart `iTerm` reopens with the correct number of tabs and windows but all without the textual history and at `~`.

This is the only app I have which is not restart proof...

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: iTerm2 has no support for this. This ticket can be used to track the implementation: https://code.google.com/p/iterm2/issues/detail?id=2775

Comment: @JörnZaefferer that link has expired, do you know where to find the updated link?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's [a duplicate on Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/198245/1595). **tl;dr:** install the latest iTerm2 beta 2.9+, and make sure your Mac is set to [*not* close windows when quitting an app](https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/issues/3717#note_1733467). The new version of iTerm2 restores windows and working directories automagically!

Comment: Dropping this comment in case someone reaches out here. The problem is that the clicking system preferences button doesn't take to the correct location where the actual setting lies. In macOS Ventura, it's in *Settings > Desktop & Dock > Windows & Apps (section/above the stage manager or default browser)* Hope it helps the next person.